# ReadJson and WriteJson works with Divan couchdb but not with Newtonsoft's Json.Net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, json.net, couchdb

I have a class which contains a DateTime property which I write to couch as an array in the WriteJson override and read from the array in the JsonRead override which works fine when saving in/loading from couch with Divan.

My problem is that I pass a Newtonsoft.Json serialized string to another instance of my application (running on a seperate machine) using http but Newtonsoft doesn't fire my overrides for read/write.

Instead, Newtonsoft tries to parse the json property from a string and not an array (the default behavior of Newtonsoft's JsonConverter i think?) and I can't change the way it works as it needs to be able to integrate with documents from the old system we have.

How do I get Json.net to call my overrides for ReadJson and WriteJson?

```
public class JobResults : CouchDocument, ICanJson
{
    [JsonProperty("update-datetime")]
    public DateTime UpdateDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    [JsonProperty("job-ids")]
    public JArray JobIDs = new JArray();


    #region CouchDocument Members

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer)
        {
            base.WriteJson(writer);

            writer.WritePropertyName("update-datetime");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Year);
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Month);
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Day);
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Hour);
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Minute);
            writer.WriteValue(UpdateDateTime.Second);
            writer.WriteEndArray();

            writer.WritePropertyName("job-ids");
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (string i in JobIDs)
                writer.WriteValue(i);
            writer.WriteEndArray();
        }

        public override void ReadJson(JObject obj)
        {
            base.ReadJson(obj);

            var dt = obj["update-datetime"].Value<JArray>();
            UpdateDateTime = new DateTime((int)dt[0], (int)dt[1], (int)dt[2], (int)dt[3], (int)dt[4], (int)dt[5]);
            JobIDs = obj["job-ids"].Value<JArray>();
        }

        #endregion
}
```

Comment: hmm... Seems to be that CouchDocument doesn't inherit JsonConverter and infact inherits ICanJson which has ReadJson and WriteJson methods. I can't change the version of Divan I'm using either and I can't inherit from both ICanJson and JsonConverter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind I got it, I added the JsonConverter attribute and pointed it to a different class.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(Serializer))]
public class JobResults : CouchDocument, ICanJson
{
    [JsonProperty("update-datetime")]
    public DateTime UpdateDateTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);

    [JsonProperty("job-ids")]
    public JArray JobIDs = new JArray();
    ...
}

public class Serializer : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        ...
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(JobResults).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```